# Replace all text except "pattern" using regex

Tags: regex, replace, find

I have a piece of software that, given a regex, can perform a find and replace. It's not a coding language, so no suggestions other than regex will be useful. I have searched looking for an expression that will help me find all text *except* "pattern". The pattern is not necessarily at the start or the end of the string, and can occur multiple times. Given the string:

```
red blue yellow green orange purple blue black green white
```

and a pattern:

```
blue.*?green
```

a pattern that appears twice on the line, I am trying to select everything but. (with a view to removing the selected and leaving just the pattern).
I have tried:

```
FIND - ".*?(blue.?green)" 
REPLACE - "$1",
```

but that still leaves "white" on the end. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume `.?` is a typo, and meant to be `.+?`. If you leave off the .*? what does that give you ? Through process of elimination you'd need a `.*?` at the end right ? Well, almost right. `.*?` at the end of a regex won't match anything because it doesn't have to. On the other hand `.*` would match. I guess the big question is why you are using `.*?` at the beginning instead of `.*`. If blue and green are delimiters, what about first and last found ?

Comment: Apologies, but yes, it is a typo. If you leave off the starting ".*?" it simply replaces the pattern with itself - so no change to the text. If I use .* at the front - it is greedy and matches everything up till the second instance - so you lose the first pattern match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's usually something like this

Find `(?:(?!blue.*?green).)*(blue.*?green)?`
Replace `$1`

Expanded

```
 (?:
      (?! blue .*? green )
      . 
 )*
 ( blue .*? green )?           # (1)
```

Output

```
blue yellow greenblue black green
```

Comment: That works BEAUTIFULLY! Thanks sln. I have been beating myself up for almost a day trying to figure that one. Now I just have to sit down and figure HOW it works, but that I can do. Thanks again mate.